# Module fails to load every couple of times the browser is refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller, module

I am having a problem with a module loading once every 6-7 times my webpage is being loaded. I have a `medication.php` file and in it I am connecting to a `medication.js` javascript file. This javascript file contains I am loading a module and setting up a controller. I have tried this on chrome, and safari as well, and again when the page is originally loaded an error is thrown and is also thrown once every 7-8 times a page is refreshed. 
You can test this for yourself by reloading  [This page](http://www.viralmedcompany.com/medication.php) several times and you will find that the content will not display randomly, and **the following error is thrown**:
 
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.
 `medication.php`: Here the medication.js, and the Angular CDN are loaded. As you can see I have my `ng-app` and I also have my `ng-controller`.

```
<html ng-app="myModule1">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>Shop For Medication </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="vex/dist/css/vex.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vex/dist/css/vex-theme-os.css"/>
</head>

    <body>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color:#2a6cd6">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Med Company</a>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="background-color: #2a6cd6" role="navigation">     
                        <li ><a href="homepage.php"> Home Page</a> </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Purchase Something<span class="caret"></span> </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="vitamins.php">Vitamins</a></li>
                                <li><a href="medication.php">Medication</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="background-color:#2a6cd6"role="navigation">
                    <li><a href="./checkout.php" id="check-out"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Check Out</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#" id="sign-out"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>


            <div class="container" ng-controller="mycontroller1" ng-cloak>
                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:50%">Product</th>
                        <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
                        <th style="width:10%">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="width:10%">Subtotal</th>
                        <th style="width:20%"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <form id="medication-product-1" method="POST">  
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <img id="small-pic2" src="images/benadryl.png"></img>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 class="nomargin"><input type="hidden" name="name1" value="Benadryl">
                                                Benadryl</input>    
                                            </h4>
                                            <p>
                                                A medication which reduces itching, sneezing, coughing through because of its properties as an anti-histamine.
                                            </p>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Price"><input type="hidden" name="Price1" value=01.99> 
                                    $1.99</input>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Quantity">
                                    <input type="number" ng-model="subtotal.subtotal1" ng-init="subtotal.subtotal1=0" name="Quantity1" ng-change="changed()" id="amount1" class="form-control text-center" min="0"/>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Subtotal" id="subtotal-1" name="Subtotal"  class="text-center" ng-bind="1.99*subtotal.subtotal1"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="1"></input>
                                    <button type="button" id="button1" name="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">
                                         Add To Cart<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </form> 
                    <form id="medication-product-2" method="POST">
                            <tr>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                                            <img src="images/motrin.jpg" id="small-pic"></img>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 >
                                            <input type="hidden" name="name2" value="Motrin"></input>
                                                Motrin 
                                            </h4>
                                            <p>
                                                Pain Reliever and Fever Reducer 
                                            </p>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Price">
                                <input type="hidden" name="Price2" value="3.99">
                                    $3.99
                                </input>    
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Quantity">
                                    <input type="number" ng-model="subtotal.subtotal2" ng-change="changed2()" ng-init="subtotal.subtotal2=0" name="Quantity2"
                                     id="amount2" min="0" class="form-control text-center"></input>
                                </td>

                                <td data-th="Subtotal" id="subtotal-2" 
                                name="Subtotal" ng-bind="3.99*subtotal.subtotal2" class="text-center" >
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="step" value="2"></input>
                                    <button type="button" id="button2" name="button-2"  class="btn btn-primary">
                                         Add To Cart<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </tbody>
                    </form> 
                </table>
            </div>
        <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="vex/dist/js/vex.combined.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> vex.defaultOptions.className = 'vex-theme-os'</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/medication.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/signout.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

`medication.js`:

```
  window.onload=function(){
button1=document.getElementById("button1");
button2=document.getElementById("button2");
number1=document.getElementById("amount1");
number2=document.getElementById("amount2");
number1.value=0;
number2.value=0;
button1.disabled=true;
button2.disabled=true;

var medicine=angular.module("myModule1",[])
.controller("mycontroller1",function($scope){
        var subtotal={
            subtotal1:0,
            subtotal2:0

        }
    $scope.subtotal=subtotal;

        $scope.changed=function(){
        if(subtotal.subtotal1>0){
            button1.disabled=false;
        }
        else {
            button1.disabled=true;
        }

        }

    $scope.changed2=function(){
        if(subtotal.subtotal2>0){
            button2.disabled=false;
        }
        else{
            button2.disabled=true;
        }

    }

});


button1.onclick=function(){
    vex.dialog.buttons.YES.text="Purchase"
    vex.dialog.buttons.NO.text="Cancel"
    vex.dialog.confirm({
    message:"Are you sure you want to purchase this item?",
    callback: function(value){  
    var data=$("#medication-product-1").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'./php/add-medicine-to-cart.php',
        data:data,

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
});
}
button2.onclick=function(){
    vex.dialog.buttons.YES.text="Purchase"
    vex.dialog.buttons.NO.text="Cancel"
    vex.dialog.confirm({
    message:"Are you sure you want to purchase this item?",
    callback: function(value){  
    var data=$("#medication-product-2").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'./php/add-medicine-to-cart.php',
        data:data,

        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
});

};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one needs to place the angular.js file in the head in order to "avoid the flash of uncompiled content". If you dont do this then one must use `ng-cloak`. Although it uncommon to place the angular.js file in the head, content will not always load unless its done in this case. Please anyone feel free to add onto my answer as to why this fixed the problem.